# building and linking a shared library

Tags: g++, cygwin, shared-libraries

im trying to build a shared library on a windows cygwin platform using g++, and later link it with another cpp file:
i use the following commands:

```
// generate object file

g++ -g -c -Wall -fPIC beat11.cpp -o beat11.o

// to generate library from the object file

g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libbeat.so.1 -o libbeat.so.1.0.1 beat11.o -lc

// to link it with another cpp file; -I option to refer to the library header file

g++ -L. -lbeat -I . -o checkbeat checkbeat.cpp
```

while linking, the following error crops up:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: 
     cannot find -llibbeat.so.1.0.1

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the library gets created just fine, but i can only find libbeat.so.1.0.1, not libbeat.so or libbeat.so.1(or are they not supposed to be there?)

one of the other questions suggests creating a symlink to libbeat.so.1.0.1, but that too didnt work

Answer (score 24):

When using `-l<libname>` to specify library to link, the linker will first search for `lib<libname>.so` before searching for `lib<libname>.a`.

In your case it doesn't work, because the library filename is not with `.so` suffix.

You may create simlink

```
libbeat.so -> libbeat.so.1.0.1
```

or

```
libbeat.so -> libbeat.so.1
libbeat.so.1 -> libbeat.so.1.0.1
```

You can also use `-l:libbeat.so.1.0.1` (if your linker supports it, check in `man ld` description of `-l` parameter). Another option is to specify the library without `-l`

```
g++ -o checkbeat checkbeat.cpp -I . -L. libbeat.so.1.0.1
```

Note that the library you link to should be put after object/source file using its symbols - otherwise the linker may not find the symbols.

Comment: I had the same problem and your comment using -l:libname.so worked. However, I don't really understand why it doesn't work with -L<Path> -lname as you said that the linker should search for lib<name>.so as well. it was also my understanding that it should work but at least with cygwin it doesn't seem to be the case. Havent't tried with other compilers.

Comment: The answer here helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154130/cygwin-g-linker-doesnt-find-shared-library