# OpenCL 1.1 Undefined Reference using C++ Wrappers

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, cygwin, opencl

I am trying to compile an OpenCL project under Eclipse using Cygwin Gcc/G++ compiler and i got some Undefined References for OpenCL API functions. I saw many threads about this problem, I tried the suggested solutions but I still have these errors.

Basically my code just retrieves OpenCL infos about the platform and device I use so I dont give it here but I can if you want (even if I dont think it is very interesting).

Here is my makefile :

```
RM := rm -rf

OpenCLEnvInfos.o: ../OpenCLEnvInfos.cpp
       g++ -IINCLUDE_DIR1 -IINCLUDE_DIR2 -g3 -Wall -c ../OpenCLEnvInfos.cpp -o     OpenCLEnvInfos.o
       @echo ' '

OpenCL_infos.o: ../OpenCL_infos.cpp    
       g++ -IINCLUDE_DIR1 -IINCLUDE_DIR2 -g3 -Wall -c ../OpenCL_infos.cpp -o OpenCL_infos.o
       @echo ' '

# All Target
all: OpenCLEnvInfos.exe

# Tool invocations
OpenCLEnvInfos.exe: OpenCLEnvInfos.o OpenCL_infos.o
       g++ -o OpenCLEnvInfos.exe OpenCLEnvInfos.o OpenCL_infos.o -LOpenCL -LGAL-fb
       @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
       -$(RM) OpenCLEnvInfos.o OpenCL_infos.o OpenCLEnvInfos.d OpenCL_infos.d     OpenCLEnvInfos.exe
       @echo ' '
```

I tried everything (Libs order in linking command), -l instead of -L (but the compiler doesnt find them) ... Eclipse makefile generation make more errors occurs that's why I had to rewrite it...

I hope someone has the answer :p

Baptiste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misuse compiler switches. Read the GCC manual for more information.

With `-L` you should provide the path to the directory where to search for libraries. In your case, where `libOpenCL.a` or `OpenCL.a` are located. For example:

```
-LD:/Libraries/OpenCL/lib
```

With `-l` you specify the library you want to link against. In your case, that would be `libOpenCL.a` or `OpenCL.a`. Like this:

```
-lOpenCL
```

The order is correct. In other words, you should keep these `-l` switches **after** all `*.o` files (in the invocation of `g++` for linkage stage) if these `*.o` files depend on the libraries specified by `-l`, what in your case is indeed true.

Comment: well the thing is I had this -LLIB_DIRECTORY before with my -lLIB1 and -lLIB2 (they are libOpenCL.so and libGAL-fb.so) but my compiler couldnt find them. Then I tried with -L and I hadnt error messages anymore. That's strange cause any thread on internet said it should be -lOpenCL for a libOpenCL.so but I never managed to do that...

Comment: i will try it tomorrow (it s for my work :/) i asked it as soon as i get home. i will tell you if i find a solution !!

Comment: ok so i used a different compiler (it s for an embedded linux on a arm9 electronic board) and it worked well with the -l prefix to use my shared libraries.

anyway i tried again with the g++ compiler provided by cygwin and it didnt work as yesterday. I found this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154130/cygwin-g-linker-doesnt-find-shared-library which i will try tomorrow (i dont have internet access at my work yet ><) and i will tell you tomorrow if thats the solution