# Run Linux Makefile on Windows (.so file)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, makefile, ld

I'm transferring to a Windows computer, and need to run my Makefile written on Linux to create a library.

```
    HEADER=/usr/include
    INCLUDEDIR=include
    LIB_NAME=libpce.so
    SO_NAME=$(LIB_NAME).3.2
    REAL_NAME=$(SO_NAME).5
    SHARED_LIB=bin/$(REAL_NAME)

    mkdir $(HEADER)/libpce
    cp $(INCLUDEDIR)/pce.h $(HEADER)/libpce
    chmod 644 $(HEADER)/libpce/pce.h
    cp $(SHARED_LIB) /usr/lib/
    ln -f -s $(SO_NAME) /usr/lib/$(LIB_NAME)
    chmod 644 /usr/lib/$(REAL_NAME)
    ldconfig
```

The output of running it through a cygwin terminal on windows gives an error as ldconfig is not defined, so I tried running them without the ldconfig command at the end.

Then when I need to run my other Makefile to compile my code with argument -lpce, it says -lpce is not defined. I feel like ldconfig was essential, but I'm not able to run it on Windows.

Is there any way to execute this command on Windows? Is this the problem, or could it potentially be an issue with the /usr/lib/ paths?

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile is full of Linux-specific commands and paths. They don't translate 1:1. Maybe you can get it sorted out, but the real solution is not to hand-write your makefiles. Use a build system like [cmake](https://cmake.org), which will generate the necessary build files for you no matter what system you're on.

You also don't mention what you have set up on your Windows machine. Windows by default does not come equipped to compile C++ code. You have to install something, whether it's the [MS Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16), [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org)/[MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org), or [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com).

Although, looking closer, your makefile snippet is nothing more than a bash script. That could probably get translated to a PowerShell script if you end up staying in a 100% Windows environment.

Comment: I'm using Cygwin to run these commands, equipped with g++ afterwards to compile my C++ code. I will take a look at cmake or a powershell script though, thanks!

Comment: I must have skimmed over that fact, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

`ldconfig` is not necessary on cygwin.

`-lpce` does not word because you have a `libpce.so`, but the linker is looking for a DLL. The solution is to create a symlink:

```
ln -s libpce.so libpce.dll
```

To go deeper, take a look at:

- [cygwin g++ Linker doesn't find shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154130/cygwin-g-linker-doesnt-find-shared-library)
- https://cygwin.cygwin.narkive.com/p5nSKm3o/ldconfig

Comment: I've tried this as well as the links provided, but I still get the error that ld cannot find -lpce