# gcc,cygwin: Unable to find depending library when creating library

Tags: gcc, cygwin, ld

Why cannot ld find the library libjarray.so below?

`gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libjstring.so.0.1  -I/home/jocke/development/jstring/../jarray/output -I/home/jocke/development/jstring -L/home/jocke/development/jstring/../jarray/output -ljarray jstring.o -o libjstring.so.0.1`

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ljarray
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

`$ ls -l /home/jocke/development/jstring/../jarray/output
total 79<br>
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jocke Domain Users    41 Oct 29 11:58 jarray.c -> /home/jocke/development/jarray/jarray.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 jocke Domain Users  9840 Oct 29 11:25 jarray.o
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jocke Domain Users    52 Oct 29 11:58 jarray_test.c -> /home/jocke/development/jarray/utest/jarray_test.c
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jocke Domain Users    16 Oct 29 11:58 libjarray.so -> libjarray.so.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jocke Domain Users 62905 Oct 29 11:58 libjarray.so.0.1`

Comment: "-ljarray" option makes ld to use archive file "libjarray.ar" for linking.  "Why cannot ld find the library libjarray.so below?" Because ld will not find "libjarray.so" but "libjarray.ar".

Comment: So you mean this is wrong: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html?

"
Telling GCC where to find the shared library

Uh-oh! The linker doesn’t know where to find libfoo. GCC has a list of places it looks by default, but our directory is not in that list.2 We need to tell GCC where to find libfoo.so. We will do that with the -L option. In this example, we will use the current directory, /home/username/foo:

$ gcc -L/home/username/foo -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
"

Comment: And, if you think that is wrong - how should you write it?

Comment: This post also suggest you are wrong, Fumu
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary

Answer (score 0):

Here I found the solution to my problem:

[building and linking a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749058/building-and-linking-a-shared-library)

I needed a specific syntax to make it work, similar to:

-l:libbeat.so.1.0.1