# Link a shared library with g++

Tags: g++

I've got a cpp file `a.cpp` and a shared object `libA.so` it's gonna use under the same folder, however, when I tried to use g++ to link them together, it declares that it cannot find the library (I checked with `ldd` afterwards).

This is the command I used 
`g++ a.cpp -I . -L. -lA`

Any idea how this might be solved?

Possible duplicates:
[building and linking a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749058/building-and-linking-a-shared-library)

Comment: Do you mean you checked with `ldd` rather than `ld`? Anyway, you need to tell the run time linker how to find the library, it's not enough to tell `g++` how to find it. There are thousands of duplicate questions, search for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: This is already mentioned in a comment on the question you linked from earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208932/link-so-file-to-cpp-file-via-g-compiling#comment42899795_27208932

Comment: Found the answer from this post http://gernotklingler.com/blog/creating-using-shared-libraries-different-compilers-different-operating-systems/

Answer (score -1):

use 
g++ -o a a.cpp -I . -L. your-so-name.so